# Having trouble with IBM Watson Language Translation API from Chinese to English

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

Can someone confirm that IBM Watson Language Translation API works from Chinese to English? I can get Language Identify to work, but not Language Translation.  Examples:

Language Translation from French to English:
$curl -v -u "username:password" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translation/api/v2/translate?source=fr&target=en&text=je%20suis%20fou"
[response] I'm crazy

Language Translation from Chinese to English:
$curl -v -u "username:password" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translation/api/v2/translate?source=zh&target=en&text=%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC%E5%B8%82"
[response] 404 error - cannot find service matching the request database

Answer (score 0):

From the Language Translation documentation:

Today, the basic Language Translator service offers three domain-specific translation models:

- News - targeted at news articles and transcripts, it translates English to and from Arabic, Brazilian Portuguese, French, German, Italian, or Spanish. It also translates Spanish to and from French.
- Conversational - targeted at conversational colloquialisms, it translates English to and from Arabic, Brazilian Portuguese, French, Italian, or Spanish.
- Patents - targeted at technical and legal terminology, it translates Brazilian Portuguese, **Chinese**, Korean, or Spanish to English.

Reference: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/language-translator/

Based on this information, it looks like what you are trying to do is not supported because it would be Conversational.